# Azure Cosmos DB - How to Know unique document structures in a collection?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Background: We are working on a migration project wherein we have to migrate data from Azure Cosmos DB To Azure SQL Database. on analyzing the Cosmos DB we found there are different structures of documents.

Requirement: We have been looking over the internet to get a query using which we can know as to how many unique/different document structures are there. however, we have not been able to find one. Any links pointers will be appreciated. Kindly let know if any further details required.

Comment: Hackolade may be of help here. However, it will only go so deep to analyze your structure. Given that schema is (or should) be maintained at the application layer, the place ideally to look for this would be in the application's model classes.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark Brown said, we can use Hackolade to analyze our structure.
[Hackolade](https://hackolade.com/help/CosmosDB.html) was specially adapted to support the data modeling of multiple object types within one single collection - while supporting multiple collections as well - in order to support the pricing model of Cosmos DB.